# Unable to read VR Path Registry from

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, geckodriver

- Version: geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64
- Platform: Windows 10 Home Single
- Browser: Firefox: 59.0.2 (64-bits)
- Selenium: selenium-java-3.11.0
- intelliJ Idea : 2018.1 Community Edition

Hello, I'm starting to use WebDriver with Java in the intelliJ IDEA. I imported Selenium with Maven and added the dependency with the code provided in the Selenium Webpage. I downloaded geckodriver and updated Windows path. I started to code but I get an ouput that seems to me as an error. Can somebody help me out to understand what is happening?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class firstTry {
   public static void main (String [] args){
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.quit();
   }
}
```

Firefox opens and closes with no problem, but In the console I have an output that seems an error to me. As the following:

```
1522649487586   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.0
1522649487598   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:31435
1522649488194   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Lolaika\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.0neo1vgzqEe7"
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Lolaika\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1522649490188   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Lolaika\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Lolaika\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Lolaika\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1522649494926   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54726
1522649495670   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
abr 02, 2018 1:11:35 A.M. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMACIÓN: Detected dialect: W3C
1522649495872   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method shutdown on activity-stream@mozilla.org: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIObserverService.removeObserver]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://activity-stream/lib/SnippetsFeed.jsm :: uninit :: line 125"  data: no] Stack trace: uninit()@resource://activity-stream/lib/SnippetsFeed.jsm:125 < onAction()@resource://activity-stream/lib/SnippetsFeed.jsm:141 < _middleware/</<()@resource://activity-stream/lib/Store.jsm:51 < Store/this[method]()@resource://activity-stream/lib/Store.jsm:30 < uninit()@resource://activity-stream/lib/Store.jsm:153 < uninit()@resource://activity-stream/lib/ActivityStream.jsm:274 < uninit()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/browser/features/activity-stream@mozilla.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js:80 < shutdown()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/browser/features/activity-stream@mozilla.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js:196 < callBootstrapMethod()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4419 < observe()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2279 < GeckoDriver.prototype.quit()@driver.js:3270 < despatch()@server.js:557 < execute()@server.js:531 < onPacket/<()@server.js:506 < onPacket()@server.js:505 < _onJSONObjectReady/<()@transport.js:500
[Child 2272, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 2272, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/cUnable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Lolaika\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Promise rejected while context is inactive: Message manager disconnected
[Parent 5308, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 5336, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 5336, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNIN[Parent 5308, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 8788, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 8788, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109*** UTM:SVC TimerManager:registerTimer called after profile-before-change notification. Ignoring timer registration for id: telemetry_modules_ping
[GPU 10500, Chrome_ChildThread] WARN
###!!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv
1522649503244   geckodriver::marionette ERROR   Failed to stop browser process
Process finished with exit code 0
```

What can I do to fix this output?

[image: My Workspace]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With *GeckoDriver v0.20.0* and *Firefox Quantum  v59.0.2 (64-bits)* your code block looks good and the log stack trace looks equally good enough sans the *log message* :

```
Promise rejected while context is inactive: Message manager disconnected
```

As per the discussion in [**Mozilla Support Forum**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1156144) this error seems to be **Privacy Badger**. In short this issue is caused by an extension that isn't loaded/working properly.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Firefox* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Firefox*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

### tl;dr

[**Are unresolved promises rejected prior to a window.unload event?**](https://github.com/w3ctag/promises-guide/issues/44)

---

### Update

Well, as I mentioned in my Answer your stack trace was *fair* enough as per current implementations. But personally I haven't seen this trace on my *localhost* :

```
Promise rejected while context is inactive: Message manager disconnected
```

Of-coarse some traces can be dependent of the underlying *OS*. Now going through the entire discussion [**Are unresolved promises rejected prior to a window.unload event?**](https://github.com/w3ctag/promises-guide/issues/44) the bottom-line seems :

> The problem of promises from unloading pages (or indeed script invocation in unloaded pages in general) not being specified very well and not being interoperably implemented is very real. See also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1058695 where we ended up putting in some mitigations in Gecko that technically don't follow the spec, because technically following the spec requires leaking the world in common cases.... The problem is that there is no spec for this event loop stuff right now, and the spec for Promise is part of ES6, which doesn't really doesn't admit the possibility of Realms needing to go away in some sense, so there's nothing to even raise such issues against.

Hence the conclusion is **You are good to race ahead**

Comment: The SDK version that I'm running is JDK 9.
Selenium version is 3.11.0
How can I clean the Project Workspace in intelliJ IDEA?
I used CCleaner tool and clean barely everything.
The firefox is the latest version: Firefox: 59.0.2 (64-bits)
Rebooted the system several times.
The @Test is when you use junit, right? but in this moment I'm not using it, should I include junit? Still cannot get rid of the console messages. :(

Comment: @LolaikaBadtzMaru Check out my Answer update and let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Well It seems to be running the same, anyways... Thanks! I will try different IDE to see if the same thing happens. :)