# Unable to read VR Path Registry

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run this code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/webdriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
time.sleep(8)
driver.quit()
```

But it's showing this error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12453/devtools/browser/cca5e95f-faba-4ea4-afa0-f922355e2398

Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Achilies\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: This is the problem ------->           Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Achilies\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath

Comment: Does this file exist?

Comment: No the file is not exist

Comment: is that the full error log?

Comment: Yes its the full log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to read VR Path Registry from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606422/unable-to-read-vr-path-registry-from)